# Printed the data from two files in to console , now i want to merge the both data and print in one file using prinWriter

Tags: java

*Printed the data from two files in to console , now i want to merge the both data and print in one file using printWriter*
for this am using the following code ,

```
import java.io.*;
class DataM 
{

   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.txt"));

        BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("def.txt"));

        String line=br.readLine();

        while(line!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);

            line=br.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("****************************************************************************");
        String line2=br1.readLine();

        while(line2!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line2);

            line2=br1.readLine();
        }

        //PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter();
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter("ilm.txt");      

        pw.println(br);
        pw.println(br1);
        pw.println();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is stopping you? At the time you write to console you can also write that `line` to file. What is the purpose of `pw.println(br);`?

Comment: You can easily do this using BufferedWriter, try with that.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you want to print the results of the two files in order, however you have taken the approach:

```
 pw.println(br);
 pw.println(br1);
```

This won't work because those two objects are instances of a Reader. A reader, when called to be a String won't return its contents. So our option here is to store those lines you printed and instead write to the file that way.

So, when you read those two files, let's do this

```
 List<String> lines=new ArrayList<>();
 String line=br.readLine();
 while(line!=null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    lines.add(line);

    line=br.readLine();
}
System.out.println("****************************************************************************");
String line2=br1.readLine();

while(line2!=null)
{
    System.out.println(line2);
    lines.add(line2);

    line2=br1.readLine();
}
```

This will store all those lines so we can write to a file ourselves. 
Now to do that...

```
try(PrintWriter stream=new PrintWriter(new File("ilm.txt"))) {

        lines.forEach(stream::println);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This simply opens a new PrintWriter to write to the file with, similarly to what you have done, where we can write and close the stream automatically.